# Isn't the direction of propagation wrong in this diagram from wikimedia commons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

The direction of propagation of an electromagnetic wave is given by the Poynting Vector

\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \boldsymbol{E} \times \boldsymbol{B}.
\end{equation}

This diagram shows the direction in the opposite direction.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it! Happens sometimes.

Comment: The lambda (λ) symbol is also inverted.

Comment: Good catch! Someone has already poynted this out on the [discussion page.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File_talk:Electromagnetic_waves.png) It is only used in the wikis for Afrikaans and some language in India.